# Join expression not supported occured when left join two worksheets from two different workbooks

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I would like to left join two worksheets from two different workbooks. Below is my code and I encountered error 'JOIN expression not supported' when I executed the sql.

```vb
Sub RunSELECT()
Dim cn As Object, rs As Object, output As String, sql As String
Dim pre_reviewed_file As String, cond As String

Dim fso As Object, outfile As String, file_obj As Object

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
outfile = "C:\Users\ZhouK\Desktop\offline comments\offline-comments\result.txt"
Set file_obj = fso.CreateTextFile(outfile, True)


pre_reviewed_file = "56022473AML2002 OFFLINE listings 20161010 - reviewed.xls"


'MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.FullName
'---Connecting to the Data Source---
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
    .Open
End With

cond = "1=1"

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("LIS01").Rows(3)
    For i = 1 To 24
        cond = cond & " and a.[" & .Cells(i).Value & "]=b.[" & .Cells(i).Value & "]"
    Next
End With

sheet_name = "LIS01"

'---Run the SQL SELECT Query---
sql = "SELECT b.[COMMENTS] FROM [" & sheet_name & "$A3:AZ3000] a left join [Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;Database=" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & _
        "\" & pre_reviewed_file & ";].[" & sheet_name & "$A3:AZ3000] b on " & cond

file_obj.Write (sql)
file_obj.Close

Set rs = cn.Execute(sql)
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("me").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

'Do
   'output = output & rs(0) & ";" & rs(1) & ";" & rs(2) & vbNewLine
   'Debug.Print rs(0); ";" & rs(1) & ";" & rs(2)
   'rs.Movenext
'Loop Until rs.EOF

'MsgBox output

'---Clean up---
rs.Close
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

The real sql is

```sql
select b.[COMMENTS] 
from [LIS01$A3:AZ3000] a 
left join [Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\Users\ZhouK\Desktop\offline comments\offline-comments\56022473AML2002 OFFLINE listings 20161010 - reviewed.xls;].[LIS01$A3:AZ3000] b 
on 1=1 and a.[Study Site Identifier]=b.[Study Site Identifier] 
and a.[Unique Subject Identifier]=b.[Unique Subject Identifier] 
and a.[CM Record Number]=b.[CM Record Number] 
and a.[Medication]=b.[Medication] 
and a.[Indication]=b.[Indication] 
and a.[AE-Date-Term1]=b.[AE-Date-Term1] and a.[AE-Date-Term2]=b.[AE-Date-Term2] and a.[AE-Date-Term3]=b.[AE-Date-Term3] 
and a.[AE-Date-Term4]=b.[AE-Date-Term4] and a.[AE-Date-Term5]=b.[AE-Date-Term5] 
and a.[MH-Date-Term1]=b.[MH-Date-Term1] and a.[MH-Date-Term2]=b.[MH-Date-Term2] and a.[MH-Date-Term3]=b.[MH-Date-Term3] 
and a.[MH-Date-Term4]=b.[MH-Date-Term4] and a.[MH-Date-Term5]=b.[MH-Date-Term5] 
and a.[Prohylaxis or Other]=b.[Prohylaxis or Other] 
and a.[Dose]=b.[Dose] and a.[Dose Unit]=b.[Dose Unit] 
and a.[Dose Form]=b.[Dose Form] and a.[Frequency]=b.[Frequency] 
and a.[Route]=b.[Route] and a.[Ongoing]=b.[Ongoing] 
and a.[CM Start Date]=b.[CM Start Date] and a.[CM End Date]=b.[CM End Date]
```

I don't really know which part is wrong. Could you please take a look into my code?

Comment: Step through your code placing a breakpoint at "sheet_name = "LIS01"" and once you hit that statement query the immediate window with "?cond" and press return. That way you'll be able to compare the wanted sql string with the actually built one

Comment: @user3598756 Thanks your for your comment. I don't really get what press return means? press backspace?

Comment: in the immediate window you'll type `?cond` and then you have to press the return key to have the result of this query appear right below the query itslef

Comment: @user3598756 see what you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your SQL `JOIN` as the expression `on 1=1` is not allowed in the `ON` clause for the Jet/ACE SQL dialect. Because you needed this item to initiate the string for your loop, consider removing it after loop:

```
con = Replace(con, "on 1=1 and ", "on ")
```

Alternatively, re-write an equivalent query by moving `ON` expressions to `WHERE` clause and comma-separating the `FROM` tables. This is known as the *implicit join* as opposed to *explicit join* using `JOIN`, both of which are equal evaluation and performance:

```
select b.[COMMENTS] 
from [LIS01$A3:AZ3000] a,
[Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\Users\ZhouK\Desktop\offline comments\offline-comments\56022473AML2002 OFFLINE listings 20161010 - reviewed.xls;].[LIS01$A3:AZ3000] b 
where 1=1 and a.[Study Site Identifier]=b.[Study Site Identifier] 
and a.[Unique Subject Identifier]=b.[Unique Subject Identifier] 
and a.[CM Record Number]=b.[CM Record Number] 
and a.[Medication]=b.[Medication] 
and a.[Indication]=b.[Indication] 
and a.[AE-Date-Term1]=b.[AE-Date-Term1] and a.[AE-Date-Term2]=b.[AE-Date-Term2] and a.[AE-Date-Term3]=b.[AE-Date-Term3] 
and a.[AE-Date-Term4]=b.[AE-Date-Term4] and a.[AE-Date-Term5]=b.[AE-Date-Term5] 
and a.[MH-Date-Term1]=b.[MH-Date-Term1] and a.[MH-Date-Term2]=b.[MH-Date-Term2] and a.[MH-Date-Term3]=b.[MH-Date-Term3] 
and a.[MH-Date-Term4]=b.[MH-Date-Term4] and a.[MH-Date-Term5]=b.[MH-Date-Term5] 
and a.[Prohylaxis or Other]=b.[Prohylaxis or Other] 
and a.[Dose]=b.[Dose] and a.[Dose Unit]=b.[Dose Unit] 
and a.[Dose Form]=b.[Dose Form] and a.[Frequency]=b.[Frequency] 
and a.[Route]=b.[Route] and a.[Ongoing]=b.[Ongoing] 
and a.[CM Start Date]=b.[CM Start Date] and a.[CM End Date]=b.[CM End Date]
```